# Arduino Ethernet Shield - GET - WebClient - 400 Bad Request

Tags: arduino

I have problem with sending data using GET in PHP in my Arduino. I open WebClient code from Arduino IDE, just change char server[] and get things.

I use that code to add record to my MySQL database.

```
http://cineksuw.hol.es/mysql.php?d=10&t=20&h=30&p=40
```

As you can see it work so I try to do this using arduino:

```
char server[] = "http://cineksuw.hol.es";

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
  Serial.println("connected");
  // Make a HTTP request:
  client.println("GET /mysql.php?d=1&t=5&h=1&p=4 HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: http://cineksuw.hol.es");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println();}
```

But this code dont work, i get that:

```
    connecting...
connected
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.9.3
Date: Tue, 13 Oct 2015 10:42:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 172
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.3</center>
</body>
</html>

disconnecting.
```

What is the problem ? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Both in `client.connect` and in the `Host` header you should be using just the domain name, not an HTTP address. I.e.:

```
char server[] = "cineksuw.hol.es";
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
...
```

and

```
client.println("Host: cineksuw.hol.es");
```

Comment: Thanks, I change that but still is problem. Now there is no connection.
`connecting...
connection failed

disconnecting.
`
But when I change `char server` to google.com again it connect with no problem. My website is ok and work.